# Can you explain what this regex does in ksh?

Tags: regex, unix, grep, ksh

```
grep -i "^--[ ]*dependency" "$dir/${script[${array_len}]}"|grep -v -i ":[     ]*none[         ]*$"
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know what exactly are those `[     ]*` and `none[         ]`. They probably contain a tab as well as a space.

Comment: Yes, 1st square bracket is space and the last 2 are tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This consists in two `grep` expressions, so let's check one after the other:

- **`grep -i "^--[ ]*dependency"`**

This checks all lines that match the pattern `"^--[ ]*dependency"`. This pattern says: lines starting (`^`) with `--` and followed by any amount of spaces (0, 1 or many) and followed by the text `dependency` case-insensitive.

See it working:

```
$ cat c
--         dependency
--dependency
-dependency
$ grep -i "^--[ ]*dependency" c
--         dependency
--dependency
```

- **`grep -v -i ":[     ]*none[         ]*$"`**

This checks all lines that do not match the pattern `":[     ]*none[         ]*$"`.

This pattern says: lines containing `:` followed by any amount of tabs (0, 1 or many), then the text `none` case-insensitive and finally any amount of tabs (0, 1 or many) to end the line.

All together, this is checking for lines that start with `--` + spaces + `dependency` and not ending with `:` + tabs + `none` + tabs.

---

Footnote. Flags used in `grep` here:

- `-i` Ignore case distinctions in both the PATTERN and the input files.
- `-v` Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.